# Show that $\{x \in X: \|f(x) \|+... +\| f^{(p)}(x) \| \geq \varepsilon\}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, compactness

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ Denote $E$ a Banach space with strictly convex norm. 
Denote $C_0^p(X,E)$ the Banach space consisting of all $E$-valued functions which have up to $p$-th times continuous derivatives on $X$ and vanish at infinity, that is, the set
$$A = \{x \in X: \|f(x) \|+...+\| f^{(p)}(x) \| \geq \varepsilon\}$$
is compact for all $\epsilon>0.$

> Question: For any $f\in C_0^p(Q,E),$ why is the set $A$ compact for any $\varepsilon$?

I am thinking to show the set is closed and bounded.

For closeness, suppose $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ and converges to $x.$ We want to show that $x \in A.$ I think it has something to do with continuity of $f$, but do not know how to proceed.

For boundedness, I have no clue how to start.

---

EDITED (23/04/19): The definition above of 'vanishing at infinity' is obtained from [this paper by Lei Li et al](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afa/1512982818).

Comment: Heine-Borel theorem is valid only for subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: A compact set in a metric space must be bounded but $A$ isn't necessarily so. Take $E = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and $\rho$ to be the usual taxicab metric on $\mathbb R^{p+1}$. Let $C_0^p(X, E)$ have the sup norm. Then there are smooth functions whose norm can be arbitrarily large. They all belong to your set $A$ but their norms don't converge so $A$ is unbounded. 

Perhaps you mean $< \varepsilon$?

Comment: $X $ is a subset of $\mathbb {R}$.so why can't I use Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: I misread the set $A$, my bad. But then, what is $f$? Are you fixing $f \in C_0^p(X, E)$?

Comment: Do all of the $p$ derivatives vanish as well?

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited my post. The definition of vanishing at infinity is quite different from the 'common' definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $f \in C_0^p(X, E)$ is fixed. The composition

$$ \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{p+1} \to [0, \infty) $$

where the first map sends $x$ to the tuple $(f(x), f'(x), \cdots, f^{(p)}(x))$ and the second is the $\rho$ map, is continuous because each map is continuous. Hence $A$, which is the preimage of $[\varepsilon, \infty)$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.

$A$, being a closed subset of the compact set $\{ x \in X : \Vert f(x) \Vert \geq \varepsilon\}$ must be compact as well.

Comment: How about boundedness?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Why is the first map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ continuous? Furthermore, the tuple $(f(x),...,f^{(p)}(x))$ is an element in $E^{p+1}.$

Comment: The containment in the last line goes the other way.

Comment: The article is behind a paywall so I am unable to access it.