# For continuously differentiable $f,$ is it true that the set $\{(x_0,x_1)\in (0,1)^2: |f(x_0)| + |f'(x_1)| \geq \epsilon\}$ not compact in $(0,1)^2?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

**Notations:** We denote $C_0^1(0,1)$ the collection of all real-valued continuously differentiable function $f$ on $(0,1)$ that vanish at boundary, that is, for any $\epsilon>0,$ the set 
$$\{x\in (0,1): |f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$$
is compact in $(0,1).$

---

> **Question**: For any $f\in C_0^1(0,1)$ and any $\epsilon>0,$ is it true that the set 
>   $$\{(x_0,x_1)\in (0,1)^2: |f(x_0)| + |f'(x_1)| \geq \epsilon\}$$
>   not compact in $(0,1)^2?$

Intuitively the statement seems correct as $f$ and $f'$ may not 'vanish at infinity' at different points. 
However, I do not know how to formulate this vigorously.

Comment: Vanishing at infinity is not a tight restriction on real-valued functions. I suspect that the functions could do whatever they wanted (within reason of differentiability) in the interval $(0,1).$ Did you by any chance mistype the definition of vanishing at infinity? Maybe there should there be a $1/x$ somewhere?

Comment: @Displayname I think the definition given in my post is correct. Can you elaborate on where should I add $1/x$?

Comment: The functions are defined on $(0,1)$ yet we ask about behavior at infinity. To solve this problem, $(0,1)$ can be mapped to $(1,\infty)$ by inversion.

Comment: Vanish at the boundary might be a less confusing terminology?

Comment: @copper.hat you are right. I should change to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x) = (x \sin {1 \over x} ) ((1-x) \sin {1 \over 1-x} ) $.

Note that $f$ is smooth on $(0,1)$, $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x) =0$.

The derivative is straightforward, if messy, to compute and we see that
$\limsup_{x \downarrow 0} f'(x) = \limsup_{x \uparrow 1} f'(x) = \infty$
and $\liminf_{x \downarrow 0} f'(x) = \liminf_{x \uparrow 1} f'(x) = -\infty$.

In particular, the set $\{ (x_0,x_1) | |f(x_0)|+|f'(x_1)| \ge \epsilon \}$ is
contains points of the form $(x_0(n),x_1(n))$ where $(x_0(n),x_1(n)) \to (0,0)$, 
hence the set is not compact.

Comment: May I know your intuition of obtaining such function? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: In what way? ${}$

Comment: How can this set be unbounded? It is still a subset of $(0,1)^2$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: If we just restrict to one point instead of two points, then would the set be compact? In other words, is the set $\{x\in (0,1): |f(x)| + |f'(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ compact?

Comment: @Idonknow: No. The same reasoning applies. Take a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $f'(x_n) \to \infty$. Since $0$ is not in the set it cannot be compact.

Comment: In one of my old posts (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286447/show-that-x-in-x-fx-fpx-geq-varepsilon-is-com?rq=1), @Abhishek Parab show that if we consider one point, then it is always compact, which is contradicting with your comment above. I am kind of confused now.

Comment: What confuses you above? Pick points $x_n \to 0$ such that $f'(x_n) \to \infty$. Then $(x_n,x_n)$ is in the above set or all $n$ sufficiently large and $(x_n,x_n) \to (0,0)$ which is **not** in the above set. I think the proof in the referenced question has an error.